# Rearrange and get equivalent value on PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way on PHP where I can get the **arrangement** of the strings inside `$input` array:

```
$input = array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "one"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "two"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "three"
}
```

Then use the `$reference` array as **reference for the equivalent**

```
$reference = array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "2"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "two"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "3"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "three"
    }
    [2]=>
        array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "1"
        [1]=>
        string(3) "one"
    }
}
```

And result to the `$output` array?

```
$output = array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "3"
}
```

Comment: Why not making reference array something like this if I understood your questions rightly.


    $reference = array(
        "one"=>"1",
        "two"=>"2",
        "three"=>"3",
    )

Comment: What I did in my answer is take the existing array and create what @TalhaMalik suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reindex your reference array by the second column ("two", "three", etc.) using `array_column`.

```
$words = array_column($reference, 0, 1);
```

Then get your output by looking up the key corresponding to each value from `$input` in the reindexed array.

```
$output = array_map(function($x) use ($words) {
    return $words[$x];
}, $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
foreach ($reference as $value){
    $new_ref[$value[1]] = $value[0];
}

foreach($input as $in){
    $output[]=$new_ref[$in];
}

var_export($output);
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/24a86ccc5e3a7e1e994bf5ceb0814757fd910a10)

The first thing I did was make a new array were the KEY matches up to the INPUT then I assigned the value of the items with those KEYS to the output array.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case isnt very clear, but i imaging you can use `array_flip`:

```
$input = ['one','two','three'];
$flipped = array_flip($input);

echo $flipped['one']; //0 - arrays in php are zero based
echo $flipped['three']; //2 - arrays in php are zero based
```

If you really need the `$reference` array as described, then a simple loop will do:

```
$reference=[];
foreach($input as $key=>$value)
    $reference[]=[$key+1, $value];
```